# collection record is empty return in meteor . why?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I am trying a react with meteor crud operation example that has google and default account login. The user login is displayed as its own record.

The `createContainer` function is returning contacts as `[ ]`, why ?

First I tried login with google account and its working fine. After that I added meteor accounts ui and accounts password. Then its giving me null contacts. So something must be missing here to use meteor account ui.

Here is what I have done.

**list.jsx**

```
export default createContainer(() => {

    return {
        contacts: Contact.find({}).fetch(),
        user: Meteor.user(),
    };

}, ContactList);
```

**my schema:-**

```
export const Contact = new Mongo.Collection('contact');


Meteor.methods({

'contacts.insert'(firstName,lastName,email,password){
     if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
        }

    ContactSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    "firstName": {
        type: String
    },

    "lastName": {
        type: String
    },
    "email": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        label: "E-mail address"
    },
    "password": {
        type: String,
        min:6,
        label:'password at least 6 character'
    },
    "owner": {type: String},
    "createdAt": {type: Date}
 });

Contact.insert({
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    password,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    owner: Meteor.userId()
});

Contact.attachSchema(ContactSchema);

 },
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.fetch()` method is not reactive, so what is passed to the container is the current state of the cursor. The most probable issue is that the initialization happens before data is fetched from the server, hence the collection is still empty.

Just remove the `.fetch()` method and pass the data as a reactive cursor: `contacts: Contact.find({}),`. Of course, in the container use cursor methods as opposed to array ones. Then the container will refresh itself once new data appears.

Comment: so no need anything code. i got solution. i updated package so working fine.